# Как получить путь к рабочему столу через cmd?

Tags: cmd, bat

Как получить путь к рабочему столу через командную строку? Т.е. нужно открыть папку рабочего стола, не зная пути до рабочего стола. Может быть есть какие либо переменные окружения для этого?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Через запрос из реестра можно получить список всех папок

Для рабочего стола `/v Desktop`

```
REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Desktop
```

Он же

```
%USERPROFILE%\Desktop
```

Comment: Плохо - папка Desktop зависит от текущей локали. Может называться и "Рабочий стол" на русскоязычной винде. Также не рассмотрен вопрос WinXP vs Win7

Comment: Afaik, не зависит. "Рабочий стол" — это всего лишь синоним для Desktop.

Comment: @gecube, насколько я знаю, от xp до win7 рабочий стол имеет путь с именем `desktop`, будь то китайская или русская винда

Comment: @Doofy, на более старших виндах - так же